# buefy tabla con filas detalladas personalizadas

Tags: vue.js, tablas, buefy

lo que quiero realizar es un tabla en la cual se pueda hacer click a un boton y este te traiga el detalle de de la informacion de esa fila, lo cual quiero lograrlo con buefy, pero no entiendo del todo el ejemplo mostrado en la documentacion online oficial.

Un ejemplo de lo que quiero realizar esta en esta direccion : https://buefy.org/documentation/table/#custom-detailed-rows

Esta es la parte del ejemplo es lo que me interesa y lo he adaptado con la informacion que tengo:

```
      <b-table
        :data="herramientas"
        ref="table"
        detailed
        hoverable
        custom-detail-row
        :opened-detailed="['Board Games']"            
        detail-key="name"
        @details-open="(row, index) => $buefy.toast.open(`Expanded ${row.name}`)"
        :show-detail-icon="showDetailIcon">

        <template slot-scope="props">

            <b-table-column label="Descripcion" >{{props.row.Descripcion}}</b-table-column>
            <b-table-column label="Marca" >{{props.row.Marca}} </b-table-column>
            <b-table-column label="Condicion" >{{props.row.Condicion}}</b-table-column>
            <b-table-column label="Referencia" >{{props.row.Referencia}}</b-table-column>

        </template>

        <template slot="detail" slot-scope="props">
            <tr v-for="item in props.row.items" :key="item.Descripcion">
                <td v-if="showDetailIcon"></td>
                <td>{{ item.Descripcion }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.nota }}</td>
                
            </tr>
        </template>
    </b-table>
```

en vuejs tengo esta informacion:

```
  var app = new Vue({
el:'#app',
data:{
     herramientas:[
                  {"Descripcion":"Solicitud 1","Marca":"marca 1","Condicion":"Usado","Referencia":"referencia 1","Observaciones":"verde","id":"01",
             "item":[{"Descripcion": "Adaptor", "nota":"8 pulgadas"},
                    {"Descripcion": "Alicate", "nota":"9 pulgadas"},
                    {"Descripcion": "Arnes", "nota":"10 pulgadas"}]},
            {"Descripcion":"Solicitud 2","Marca":"marca 2","Condicion":"Usado","Referencia":"referencia 1","Observaciones":"verde","id":"02",
             "item":[{"Descripcion": "Adaptor", "nota":"8 pulgadas"},
                    {"Descripcion": "Alicate", "nota":"9 pulgadas"},
                    {"Descripcion": "Arnes", "nota":"10 pulgadas"}]},
             {"Descripcion":"Solicitud 3","Marca":"marca 3","Condicion":"Usado","Referencia":"referencia 3","Observaciones":"verde","id":"03",
             "item":[{"Descripcion": "Adaptor", "nota":"8 pulgadas"},
                    {"Descripcion": "Alicate", "nota":"9 pulgadas"},
                    {"Descripcion": "Arnes", "nota":"10 pulgadas"}]}
    ],
   showDetailIcon:true
   }
   })
```

La parte del codigo que no entiendo es esta:

```
        :opened-detailed="['Board Games']"
```

Si se fijan en el ejemplo "Board Games" es el nombre de una propiedad, para mi deberia ir props.row.items o en su defecto item

```
        detail-key="name"
```

Esta es la info del ejemplo de la documentacion, pero desde mi punto de vista deberia ser :key="item.Descripcion" (creo que en este lo tengo bien)

```
        @details-open="(row, index) => $buefy.toast.open(`Expanded ${row.name}`)"
```

Este ultimo no tengo idea de lo que hace, si cambio row.name por row.Descripcion  cuando le doy clic a la flecha de detalle me sale un mensajito con la info contenida en descripcion

Lo que no hace mi codigo es mostrarme el detalle, todo lo demas creo que esta bien. Si saben de algun ejemplo en alguna web o si pudieran describirme esas opciones de las tablas de buefy seria de gran ayuda. Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el template detail tienes:

```
<tr v-for="item in props.row.items" :key="item.Descripcion">
```

El valor de `props.row.items` hace referencia a items y en tu array de herramientas no se llama "items" se llama "item" mira:

```
herramientas:[
{
   "Descripcion":"Solicitud 1",
   "Marca":"marca 1",
   "Condicion":"Usado",
   "Referencia":"referencia 1",
   "Observaciones":"verde",
   "id":"01",
   "item":[{"Descripcion": "Adaptor", "nota":"8 pulgadas"}
}]
```